# How to Cast List<T> to my own Collection

Tags: c#, .net, generic-collections

I have implemented my own collection class for various reasons.
How to avoid casting failure on `ItemCollection resultCollection = (ItemCollection)list;`? I'm inheriting from `List<T>` so shouldn't I be able to cast? Can I modify my `BaseEntityCollection` to become able to do this?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ItemCollection collection = new ItemCollection();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ID = 1;
        item.Name = "John";
        collection.Add(item);
        List<Item> list = collection.FindAll(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "John");

        ItemCollection resultCollection = (ItemCollection)list; // It's breaking here
    }
}


public class ItemCollection : BaseEntityCollection<Item>
{
}

public class Item : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntityCollection<T> : List<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
}
```

I know that I can implement `FindAll`separately on my `ItemCollection` But I wanted to take advantage of all the methods available on `List<T>`.

Also I know that I can do `list.ForEach(resultCollection.Add);`. But that means iterating the collection all over again which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You have it backwards. `List<T>` must be a subclass of your own collection type for the cast to work. It must BE an instance of your collection type (maybe with some other stuff added) in order for the compiler to *use it* as an instance of your own collection type.

Comment: Why are your classes marked `partial`?

Comment: @RonBeyer There. I took it out.

Comment: Your solution may be to add functionality to `List<T>` via extension methods.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What kind of functionality?

Comment: Change your `ItemCollection` to be able to take a `List<Item>` in a constructor, then initialize the base `List<T>` class with that.

Comment: @yazanpro I haven't a clue. It's your class; I would guess that you wrote it in order to have a collection class that does something `List<T>` doesn't do. Why *did* you write it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's right. `ItemCollection` has a lot of code that I took out here. But those have nothing to do with this issue at hand.

Comment: @yazanpro Wrong. You did A to achieve B and now you have problem C *solely because you did A*. But A is very likely unnecessary; you could very likely eliminate Problem C by eliminating Mistake A, rather than adding Problem D to work around it. This is called an X Y problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Making custom collections classes is often good sense.

Comment: @Joshua It can be, yes. It can also be a mistake.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Indeed; but whether it's an X Y problem or not is in the information we can't see.

Comment: @Joshua That's why I said "may be" and "very likely", and asked OP for clarification. But from his reaction to that, I'd bet money it's x/y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ItemCollection resultCollection = new ItemCollection();
resultCollection.AddRange(collection.Where(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "John"));
```

If by chance you don't have the AddRange extension method, make it.

```
void AddRange<T>(this ItemCollection c, IEnumerable<T> items) => foreach(T i in items) c.Add(i);
```

Comment: I do have `AddRange`. But please replace `Select` with `Where`. It's just a typo there. `Select` doesn't return `IEnumrable<Item>` while `Where` does.

Comment: @yazanpro: Yeah I make the mistake of typing `select()` where I should type `where()` a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just change your constructors around so that you can initialize it with a `List<Item>` collection. This lets you initialize the item collection with another collection:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ItemCollection collection = new ItemCollection();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ID = 1;
        item.Name = "John";
        collection.Add(item);
        List<Item> list = collection.FindAll(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "John");

        ItemCollection resultCollection = new ItemCollection(list);
    }
}


public class ItemCollection : BaseEntityCollection<Item>
{
    //Allow default constructor
    public ItemCollection() { }

    //Construct with a list collection
    public ItemCollection(IEnumerable<Item> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {

    }
}

public class Item : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntityCollection<T> : List<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    //Still be able to create blank items
    public BaseEntityCollection() { }

    public BaseEntityCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
}
```

In order to avoid iterating your list twice, I would change the following:

```
List<Item> list = collection.FindAll(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "John");
```

to

```
var list = collection.Where(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "John");
```

Which will lazy-load your list (in a sorts), but it will only iterate your collection once, when you create the new `ItemCollection` from it.

Comment: Your answer is great. But Joshua's answer achieves the exact same functionality with one line. Both answers are correct though.

Answer (score 1):

To augment the already great answers. You asked:

> I'm inheriting from List so shouldn't I be able to cast?

Yes and no.

Your particular cast works at compile time but not at runtime.

Casting is a way of telling the compiler, "Trust me. This will work at runtime."

At runtime, we can cast from a `Base` class to a `Descendant` class only when the underlying object inside of `Base` is actually an object of type `Descendant`.

For instance, keeping in mind that `string` descends from `object`, here is an illustration of why your cast fails at runtime.

```
// builds but fails at runtime
object o1 = new object();
string s1 = (string)o1;     

// builds and works at runtime
// because o2 is a string in object's clothing
object o2 = (object)"";
string s2 = (string)o2;
```